# I am having trouble retaining the shape of the drawings in my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building an app with multiple fragments and half of the fragments have a custom view (let us call it canvas) where a user can draw lines by touching and dragging a finger on the canvas.

I have managed to use SharedPreferences to save (the user needs to click on save in a dropdown menu) and load the lines when a user comes back to the fragment (after either leaving for another fragment or closing the app).

However, upon loading, the original drawing changes to a group of lines (numbering equal to the amount needed to create the original drawing) originate from the top left of the canvas almost like sunrays if that makes sense.

**Before saving**

[image: Before Saving]

**After Saving and coming back to the fragment**

[image: After Saving]

I don't know why it is loading like this and not how to fix it but I believe it has something to do with the loadDrawing method. I'll show the code below (the code for the canvas fragments are basically the same so I'll show the code of one fragment.

**PaintView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.EmbossMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.MaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PaintView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 10;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
public static int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private static ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private boolean emboss;
private boolean blur;
private MaskFilter mEmboss;
private MaskFilter mBlur;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
public Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);




public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);

}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

}

public ArrayList getPaths() {
    return paths;

}

public ArrayList setPaths(ArrayList<FingerPath> list) {


    return this.paths = list;
}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    loadDrawing(mCanvas);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void normal() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = false;

}



public void clear() {
    backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    paths.clear();
    normal();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

        for (FingerPath fp : paths) {

            mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

            if (fp.emboss)
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
            else if (fp.blur)
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

            mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);
        }




    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath, x, y);

    paths.add(fp);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}


//I believe it is here that problem lies
public void loadDrawing(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mCanvas != null) {


        currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
        strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
        if (! paths.isEmpty()) {
            canvas.save();
            mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

            float xTest = 0.0f;
            float yTest = 0.0f;


            for (FingerPath fp : paths) {

                mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
                mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
                mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

                if (fp.emboss)
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
                else if (fp.blur)
                    mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

                    //need to figure out how to retain shape upon loading

                if (xTest == 0.0f && yTest == 0.0f) {
                    xTest = fp.x;
                    yTest = fp.y;

                    fp.path.quadTo(xTest, yTest, (xTest + fp.x) / 2, (yTest + fp.y) / 2);
                } else {
                    fp.path.quadTo(xTest, yTest, (xTest + fp.x) / 2, (yTest + fp.y) / 2);


                    xTest = fp.x;
                    yTest = fp.y;
                }



            }




            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

            canvas.restore();
        }

    }
}
}
```

**FingerPath.java**

```
import android.graphics.Path;


public class FingerPath{

public int color;
public boolean emboss;
public boolean blur;
public int strokeWidth;
public Path path;
public float x;
public float y;

public FingerPath(int color, boolean emboss, boolean blur, int strokeWidth, Path path, float x, float 
y) {
    this.color = color;
    this.emboss = emboss;
    this.blur = blur;
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    this.path = path;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

}


}
```

**LineLHwFragment.java**

*A fragment that contains a canvas*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LineLHwFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;
public ArrayList<FingerPath> lineLoad;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_l_hw, container, false);

        return v;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    paintView = view.findViewById(R.id.lineLPaintView);
    loadData();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            saveData();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("line test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(paintView.getPaths());
    editor.putString("line test", json);
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("line test 1", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("line test", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<FingerPath>>() {}.getType();

    lineLoad = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    if (lineLoad != null) {
        paintView.setPaths(lineLoad);
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), "Data loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


}
```